# Powershell 2 ISE, not stopping on breakpoints in imported modules

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-ise

When we set breakpoints within a Module we've imported the debugger ignores the breakpoint. Has anybody else seen this behaviour?
This is driving me nuts, we use PowerShell Modules extensively.
The thing that's really weird is I can see the breakpoint if I run get-psbreakpoint

```
PS H:\Projects\Powershell> get-psbreakpoint | format-list -force


Id       : 0
Script   : H:\projects\Powershell\Shared\SFTP\SFTP.psm1
Line     : 25
Column   : 0
Enabled  : True
HitCount : 0
Action   : 

Id       : 1
Script   : H:\projects\Powershell\Trading\CPPIB\scripts\CppibBorrowReturns.ps1
Line     : 12
Column   : 0
Enabled  : True
HitCount : 1
Action   :
```

EDIT: Seems to work if I delete the psd1 (Manifest file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debugging modules can be tough. One way I have been able to do it is load both the module and the code that calls the function you are debugging. In the code that calls a function in the module, place a break point. Then when it its the call to the function in the module, step in to it. Once it steps into the module you should be able to hit F5 again to hit your break point in the module.

Sorry if that is not as clear as it should be, still reeling from day light savings on a Monday.

Comment: That is pretty much the solution I ended up with. I'm hoping it's better in Windows 8/Server 2012...